# Acessar um list/array em uma URL JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, getjson

Estou enviando via JSON um array de strings, como eu possa acessar esse array via url?
exemplo de alguns dos testes:

> http://localhost:51746/api/Language/GetLanguageList?key=[carrengado,erro]
>   http://localhost:51746/api/Language/GetLanguageList?key={carrengado,erro}

Porem nao deu certo, alguem sabe como posso fazer isso?

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetLanguageList(List<string> keys)
{
    try
    {
        #region meu codigo

        Dictionary<string, string> key_value = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        foreach (string key in keys)
        {
            key_value.Add(key,Resources.Language.ResourceManager.GetString(key));
        }

        #endregion

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResponseApi()
        {
            Status = Status.OK,
            Message = "Sucesso",
            Response = key_value
        },
        "application/json");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResponseApi()
        {
            Status = Status.NOK,
            Message = ex.Message,
            Response = null
        },
        "application/json");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

É só repetir o nome da variável de lista que consta no seu Controller, no seu caso `keys`, quando o controller receber a requisição ele saberá que é uma lista e converterá automaticamente.

`http://localhost:51746/api/Language/GetLanguageList?keys=carregando&keys=erro`

Se você quer enviar `JSON` terá que utilizar o método POST, não se envia Objeto inteiro(no seu caso o JSON) via `GET`.

Comment: Tentei aqui, porem o parametro GetLanguageList(List<string> keys) esta vindo nulo, mesmo mandando deste jeito. Sera que tenho que usar um array ? string [] keys?

Comment: Com array ou list ele entenderia da mesma forma...

Comment: você copiou e colou a minha url no seu navegador?

Comment: Sim, também tentei sem copiar e colar.
Mesmo passando apenas um parametro o retorno esta vindo null

Comment: Tive que concatenar todas as strings e dar um split (famosa gambiarra), pois  fiquei o dia todo pesquisando e nao achei a solução :/, se alguem souber e conseguir ajudar , agradeço

Comment: @GuilhermePrado pesquisei também se havia algum caso como o seu... e não consegui encontrar nada, mals.

Comment: Tranquilo, muito obrigado, vou deixar na gambi mesmo kkkk
Mas muito obrigado pela atenção!